# Debugging project with root in PyDev/LiClipse

Tags: python, debugging, root, pydev, scapy

For a project I'm doing, which uses scapy and therefore sockets, I need to be able to debug as root.

I have already figured out how to start the interpreter as root without the system asking for permission. I added:

```
user     ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/home/user/git/Project/bin/python2.7
```

to `/etc/sudoers.tmp`. The path I used leads to the python interpreter of the virtual environment which I'm using for this project. The LiClipse project is also using this path. Now I only need to make LiClipse run the interpreter as root, but I don't want to start LiClipse as root. I just want it to use this interpreter as root when debugging. How can I do that?

Comment: @fabiozadrozny Re: your tag edit. Scapy is indeed mentioned in the question. Whether it's more relevant than `pydev` is a matter of opinion, though.

Comment: Agreed (added back scapy and changed liclipse <> pydev (as it's more related to pydev than liclipse).

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I suggest using remote debugging. You can then have the process running as whichever user it needs to, and the IDE can run independently as another user, or even on another server.

Assuming you're using PyDev in LiClipse, you can configure remote debugging by following [the documentation for remote debugging](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html).

The basic premise is that you add the `pydev` debugger library to your Python path and include the following where you need a breakpoint:

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=7788, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

Then you configure your IDE with a `pydev` instance listening at that server (`7788`) in this case.

If you want to use breakpoints from the IDE, you can add the argument `suspend=False`, and the debugger will not suspend until it encounters your breakpoints.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that!

Comment: One question - how do I add the `pydevd.py ` file to my virtual-environment interpreters pythonpath?

Comment: I've only done this in PyCharm, and the distribution contains a python egg that I installed using `easy_install` into my virtualenv, since `pip` doesn't handle eggs. I don't know how to do it using LiClipse/Eclipse + PyDev.

Comment: Just chiming in, the debugger (both in PyDev and PyCharm) can currently be installed through `pip install pydevd` (as they use the same infrastructure), although for running as root, this isn't needed -- see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34945236/110451 for a way to do that.

Comment: Did you get `pydevd` installed or did you abandon the attempt?

Answer (score 2):

In PyDev you can actually select a shell script which in turn executes the actual Python to do the run... then, you can configure your shell script to first do any special setup.

I.e.: your script could be a file named `python_on_root.sh` with contents such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
source setup_env.bash
sudo python "$@"
```

Then, in the interpreter configuration, select the `python_on_root.sh` to create an interpreter that'll execute as root.

Note that the same could be done for other interesting things -- such as running in a docker container or activating a conda environment first -- sky is the limit ;)

Comment: What's `setup_env.bash`? Does this already exist, or do I have to write it, too? I'm using `source activate` to enter the virtual environment. And what does `python "$@"` do?

Comment: That was just an example on what you can do -- it doesn't exist nor needs to exist -- it was just to show that you can do `source` something ;)

Comment: Okay, I got the sh file - now how do I select this file in the interpreter configuration menu?

Comment: Go to the `preferences > pydev > interpreters > python interpreter > new` and select that file as the interpreter. Then, to actually use it you can either make the interpreter the default or edit the launch configuration to use that interpreter (in run > debug configurations).

Comment: Okay, I made it executable with `chmod +x` and now this error shows up: `See error log for details.
No output was in the standard output when
trying to create the interpreter info for: /home/lk/gitRepository/Fuzzing/bin/activate_env.sh
The error output contains:>>/home/lk/gitRepository/Fuzzing/bin/activate_env.sh: Zeile 2: activate: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
sudo: Kein TTY vorhanden und kein »askpass«-Programm angegeben
<<` ( = `file or directory not found. sudo: no TTY found and no >>askpass<< given`). So I suppose it can't find the activate file, but it is in the same directory.

Comment: Apparently it's trying to ask for the password in sudo and can't find the TTY/askpass (so, the issue is making sure it doesn't ask for the password).

Comment: And what do I need to do about this? I added the file to the sudoers list with `viduso` like that `lk     ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/home/lk/gitRepository/Fuzzing/bin/activate_env.sh` and when I execute it manually it's not asking anymore. But LiClipse still says it's missing TTY and askpass.

Comment: Humm... the access is not for activate_env.sh, but for the python interpreter you're running with sudo inside that script right? You can try adding access to any executable in the sudoers, just to test if that's it... (and if that's it, narrow it down to the proper executable later on) another option may be configuring askpass.